# How to make SSIS Data Flow execute frequently after every 5 minutes

Tags: ssis

I am a beginner in SSIS, I want to SSIS Data Flow execute frequently after every 5 minutes.

Comment: Do you mean run the SSIS package every 5 minutes?

Comment: @ Sandra Yes I want to run it every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1- Deploying the SSIS Package :**
After you finish your SIS package development, you can deploy it to the server. There we can schedule and execute the package as well.

In Visual Studio, right-click on the project and select Deploy :
[image]

This will start the SSIS deployment wizard. Keep in mind this will deploy the entire project, with all packages included. If you want to deploy an individual package, you can right-click on the package itself and choose Deploy (since SSIS 2016).

In the first step of the wizard, we need to choose the destination (several steps are skipped since we started the wizard from Visual Studio). Enter the server name and make sure the SSIS catalog has already been created on that server. If you want, you can also create a folder to store the project in.

[image]

At the next step, you get an overview of the actions the wizard will take. Hit Deploy to start the deployment.

[image]

The deployment will go through a couple of steps:

[image]

The project has now been deployed to the server and you can find it in the catalog:

[image]

**2- Executing an SSIS Package on the Server**

Manually executing packages is one thing, but normally you will schedule packages so your ETL can run in a specific time windows (probably at night). The easiest option is SQL Server Agent. You can right-click on the Jobs node to create a new job:

[image]

In the General pane, enter a name for the job, choose an owner and optionally enter a description:
[image]

In the Steps pane, you can create a new job step :

[image]

In the job step configuration, you can enter a name for the step. Choose the SQL Server Integration Services Package type, enter the name of the server and select the package.

[image]

In the configuration tab, you can optionally set more properties, just like when executing a package manually. Click OK to save the job step. In the Schedules tab, you can define one or more schedule to execute the package on predefined points in time. Click New… to create a new schedule. In the schedule editor, you can choose between multiple types of schedules: daily, weekly or monthly. You can also schedule packages to run only once. In the example below we have scheduled the job to run every day at 1AM, except in the weekend.

In your case, set the Frequency to Daily, and set the value of Occurs once at to every 5 minutes when the job should run.

Comment: Thank you very much Sandra, you save my day and time, very special thanks.